# Proving orthogonality to every vector in a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I'm confused on how this is using what is given because it looks like we are assuming that $x \cdot v_{1...p}=0$ but we are only given that $x \cdot v_{1...j}=0$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, we are given $x\cdot v_j =0$ for all $1\leq j\leq p$, so $x\cdot v_1 = 0$, $x\cdot v_2 = 0$, ... all the way to $x\cdot v_p=0$.

Comment: But if $j$ can be less than $p$ how can we assume that $x \cdot v_p = 0$?

Comment: It says "$x$ is orthogonal to each $v_j$ for $j =  1,2 ,... p$". This means $x$ is orthogonal to each of $v_1, v_2, ..., v_p$.

Comment: So everytime I see that format of $1 \leq j \leq p$, I shouldn't assume that it's saying that $j$ can be of any value between 1 and p inclusive? Like if $p$ was $5$, couldn't $j$ be $3$, since that's greater than or equal to $1$ but less than or equal to $5$?

Comment: It's because it says for $\textbf{each}$ of $j$ in $1\leq j \leq p$ in the problem statement.

Comment: "Each $j$, for $1\leq j\leq p$", is not the same as "some $j$, with $1\leq j\leq p$".

Comment: You are a little stubborn:  You shouldn't systematically use images when you can copy formulas : you don't take into account what has said (and explained why) @amd yesterday.

Comment: Oh sorry, I posted this 14 hours ago and amd's comment was posted 11 hours ago. I didn't know this was a forum etiquette/rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment it looks like you are missing the word "each". The statement says that $x\cdot v_j=0$ for $j=1$, for $j=2$, $\ldots$, and for $j=p$.